# Logging C# Expression Tree invocation

Tags: c#, expression, expression-trees

I am looking to create a simple rules engine using expression trees starting from the example given here: https://mobiusstraits.com/2015/08/12/expression-trees/

I'm wondering how I might log the evaluation of each of the rules to that I can create a log of why the model failed the rules engine.

Ideally, I would like to have a stringlist containing a list of evaluation results for each of the  rules evaluated on a given model, eg.

"Field1 passed value X matched rule X"
"Field2 failed value X did not match rule value Y"

something along those lines. This would enable to return the stringlist back to whatever function invoked the rules engine.

I came across this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34042462/1270329, which looked promising but there is no Interpret() method on an Expression class so clearly I've missed something about that solution.

Can someone set me in the right direction. I should mention I just learned of these expression trees.

TIA

Comment: You could try to name the rule. Look for the `compiledMakeModelYearRules.TakeWhile` there is where the iteration on the rules start. You might split it there and trigger an event, so you know which rule failes.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen, thanks for the reply.  I'm a bit confused by your suggestion.  Can you provide an example illustrating what you mean by splitting?

Comment: IMO [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34047715/111794) is a better answer, because it uses built-in methods and types instead of a non-existant `Interpert` method. Rather it rewrites the expression tree to include logging.